# Displaying data from a TextBox in a DataGridView

Tags: c#

I have a `TextBox` and `DataGridView` with some data in it, and when I type any text into the `TextBox`, the data in `DataGridView` should show the result.

```
private void textBox19_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtSearch = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sdaSearch = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT item_desc FROM item_master_Idetails WHERE item_desc LIKE '%+textBox19.Text+%'",Scon);
    sdaSearch.Fill(dtSearch);
    dataGridView2.DataSource = dtSearch;
}
```

Comment: Please edit both the title and the content itself. Make the title shorter and format the code.

Comment: Refer here http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/359981/display-data-on-datagridview-cellcontentclick-event

Comment: scon is connection object of SqlConnection

Comment: First I would check the datatable (dtsearch) is populating any rows. Are you sure your table name is item_master_Idetails ?

Comment: yes my table name is correct.but what do mean by data table is populating any rows ???

Answer (score 0):

Is your textbox set to autopostback?

Also, Make sure the OnRowDataBound property in the gridview on the aspx page has it set to gvItems_RowDataBound.

Comment: i m sorry but i m not using asp.net i m using c#windows application.

Comment: Pardon me.
Please disregard my answer.